# error while importing .sql to phpMyAdmin db

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to import an SQL file to my phpMyAdmin database, the file contains tables about a restaurant application and a table about the admin login, but I have 2 unexpected errors, I really don't see what is exactly wrong with that?. here is the error message:

```
2 errors were found during analysis.

An opening bracket followed by a set of values was expected. (near "CREATE" at position 109)
Unexpected token. (near "CREATE" at position 109)
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `adminlogin` (`id`, `Username`, `Password`, `right`) VALUES (1, 'admin@gmail.com', '123', 1), CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_food` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `food_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `food_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_food` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
' at line 6
```

and here is the two tables that show errors. Any insight on that? thank you

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminlogin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `right` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `adminlogin`
--

INSERT INTO `adminlogin` (`id`, `Username`, `Password`, `right`) VALUES
(1, 'admin@gmail.com', '123', 1),

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_food`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_food` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `food_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `food_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma at the end of `INSERT` statement, instead of semicolon.